# Laravel get user API

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some problems with Laravel API about user profile.
When I login user from my React app it's giving me errors Access-Control-Allow-Origin with 403 Forbidden. This access-control-allow-origin is probably because there is 403. When I try to get user info from postman, I'm setting Bearer token with link localhost:8000/api/user, that's all... and as a response, I'm receiving html code of default Laravel (or my home page of my laravel api).

Here is how my code look like.

```
public function getAuthUser(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = JWTAuth::authenticate($request->token);

        return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
    }
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` sounds like the React ajax call might be using a different domain or port. The React ajax might be using port 80?

Comment: Problem is in 403 not in access control allow origin. Why I'm not receiving json data when I run postman.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your react app and your backend are on different servers, and the browser blocks such requests, unless you configure, on your backend, CORS.

A package like [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) might help you

Comment: I have laravel-cors, problem is not in that. Problem is why I'm not receiving json data in user.